# How to calculate user input and show on the same page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to code a BMI calculator, i'm new to javascript, so its a little task for me. I have the HTML code ready and i linked the js file.

In the javascript file i declared 2 variables that take the users input. Then i declared the result in a variable. After i made a function that displays that result on the page. But i can't get it to work. I can only put in 1 id in the result variable.

How can i get this to work?

Thanks!

When i press on the button it only shows me the `Weight`, and not the `(Number(inputWeight)) / (Number(inputLength) * Number(inputLength))`;

That's the formula to calculate BMI.

```js
var inputLength = document.getElementById('length');
var inputWeight = document.getElementById('weight');
var totalBMI = (Number(inputWeight)) / (Number(inputLength) * Number(inputLength));

function displayBMI() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your BMI is: " +
    document.myForm.weight.value;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">

  <div class="form-item">
    <label class="form-label">Length (in cm):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-input" name="length" placeholder="Type your length" id="length">
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <label class="form-label">Weight (in kg):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-input" name="weight" placeholder="Type your weight" id="weight">
  </div>

  <div class="form-button">
    <input class="button" id="submit-bmi" value="calculate" type="submit" onclick="displayBMI(); return false">
  </div>

  <p id="result" class="bmi-calculator__result js-bmiresult"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: THE JAVASCRIPT =    


<script>
var inputLength = document.getElementById('length');
var inputWeight = document.getElementById('weight');

var totalBMI = (Number(inputWeight)) / (Number(inputLength) * Number(inputLength));

function displayBMI() {

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your BMI is: " + document.myForm.weight.value;


}
</script>

Comment: Here is a better calculation: `var result = (weight/length/length)*10000;` when using kg and cm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just insert this script on your code.

```js
function displayBMI() {
  var length = Number(document.getElementById("length").value);
  var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  var result = (weight/length/length)*10000;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">

  <div class="form-item">
    <label class="form-label">Length (in cm):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-input" name="length" placeholder="Type your length" id="length">
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <label class="form-label">Weight (in kg):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-input" name="weight" placeholder="Type your weight" id="weight">
  </div>

  <div class="form-button">
    <input class="button" id="submit-bmi" value="calculate" type="submit" onclick="displayBMI(); return false">
  </div>

  <p id="result" class="bmi-calculator__result js-bmiresult"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: That works, thank you!

1 more thing, the result displays a number thats way to long : like 0.0024691358024691358

But that number needs needs to round up to 24.7.

Do i use a parseInt?

Comment: Welcome [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You should use `toFixed()` to do that. LIke, `result = result.toFixed(1);` If you are new in JS you must learn [javaScript Number Methods
](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)

Comment: If I can fulfil your need then mark it as the correct answer and vote me. [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)